# Spring Data Redis - Issue while storing Date

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I am using `Spring Boot + Spring data Redis` example to save Date into the Redis Cache. Although I used `@DateTimeFormat @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")`, but still persistance happening is long value. Look like its a millisecond.

Can somebody guide if I need to set extra configurations to persist date like `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
HGETALL users:1
1) "_class"
2) "com.XXX.entity.User"
3) "userId"
4) "1"
5) "name"
6) "John"
7) "createdDate"
8) "1542043247352"
```

Entity classes:

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RedisHash("users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long userId;
    private String name;

    @DateTimeFormat
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createdDate;
    private List<Group> groups;
}
```

*UPDATE-1:: As per suggestion I implemented, but still not working*
CustomDateSerializer.java

```
@Component
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Custom Interface

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyJsonFormat {
    String value();
}
```

**Model class**

```
@MyJsonFormat("dd.MM.yyyy") 
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
private Date createdDate;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By Using Custom Serializer, this can be solved. Ref @https://kodejava.org/how-to-format-localdate-object-using-jackson/#comment-2027

```
public class LocalDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDate> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LocalDateSerializer() {
        super(LocalDate.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        generator.writeString(value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
    }
}
```

POJO:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate createdDate;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd advise using `LocalDateTime` (or LocalDate if you prefer) instead. You can then annotate your fields with

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime createdAt;
```

using jackson's jsr310 add on:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateTimeSerializer;
```

Comment: What if I only want Date or Date With Timestamp like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`?

Comment: @PAA Write your own serializer and deserializer. Simply implement the same interface as Jackson’s de-/serializer does